# Why appeared error in toolbox in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2022

I have a C++ project in Visual Studio 2022 and suddenly it has appeared in toolbox this:

[image]

Comment: Does this problem persist if you restart Visual Studio?

Comment: Have you tried repairing Visual Studio?

Comment: I had the same problem. It still worked correctly. An upgrade to the latest VS2022 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've googled the GUID from your image, and got [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-c-resource-editor-package-did-not-load-corr/315181).

So it appears that the strings that needs to be displayed there should be loaded from the `resedit.dll`, and that failed for some reason.

If the simple restart of the Visual Studio doesn't fix it (and I doubt that it will), you may want to repair your installation.